# Is there any way to return an entire line of a .txt document?

Tags: java, string, return, java.util.scanner, carriage-return

I'm currently working on a java program that requires you to use several scanners on several txt files to return definitions of names, as well as a few numbers that go along with them about their popularity. Currently, I'm having difficulty returning this data back to the original program.
 An example of how the .txt File with the definitions is as follows:

```
    ADAMO m Italian Italian form of ADAM
    ADAN mf (no meaning found)
    ADANNA f Igbo Means "father's daughter" in Igbo.
    ADANNAYA f Igbo Means "her father's daughter" in Igbo.
    ADAOIN f Irish Modern form of TAN
```

My program currently looks like this thus far:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;//For reading the file.

public class BabyNamesProject {

    //This program will use user input to scan several text documents for information regarding names.
    //It will give the popularity of the name in the last few decades, it's meaning, and a Drawing Panel chart with it's popularity.
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("Names.txt");
        File g = new File("Meanings.txt");
        File h = new File("Names2.txt");
        Scanner nameCheck = new Scanner(f);
        Scanner meaningCheck = new Scanner(g);
        Scanner popularityCheck = new Scanner(h);
        Scanner Ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName = "";
        String upperUserName = "";
        String meaning = "";

        System.out.println("Hello! This application will allow you to check how popular certain names are compared to others.");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please type in your name!");
        userName = Ask.next();  
        upperUserName = userName.toUpperCase();
        if (meaningCheck.hasNext(""+ upperUserName))

        meaning = meaningCheck.next("" + upperUserName);
        System.out.println("" + meaning);
        System.out.println("" + userName +"! That's one the rarest cards in all of duel monsters!");            
    }
}
```

As you may notice, it's nowhere near finished, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to both search the .txt file, using the uppercase name the user imputs, and how to make it return the entire line. So far, it seems like plenty of searches on here have led me to carriage returns, which I at least understand how they work, but not how to use one. If anyone has time to explain something I could do to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `.nextLine()` will get you the next line. `.next()` will only get you the next token. See [Scanner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for other `nextXxxx()` available.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `nextLine()`:

```
    File f = new File("text.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    String line = s.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BufferedReader to read the text file line-by-line and do whatever you please with it.

Have a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/